# JavaScript - I need to return a random string from an array and store the index number into a variable

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble doing what the title says. I can return a random string from an array using the function below just fine. The problem is, when I try to store the index of that string from the dicePage array into a variable, it calls the function again and randomizes the number. Is there any way to save the index of the randomized string from the array without randomizing it again? Here is my code:

```
// Array of strings

var dicePage = ['r0aidLn', 'tdupQLA', 'jGmaIfG', 'n0SXrxK', 'ZZaPdaZ', 'mAvGJzi'];

// Return a random string from the array (this works)

var diceRand = function () {
    return dicePage[Math.floor(Math.random() * dicePage.length)];
}

// Save the index of the random string from the array into a variable. 
// (This does not work because the function randomizes again and 
// returns a mismatched number). 

var diceScore = dicePage.indexOf(diceRand());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dicePage = ['r0aidLn', 'tdupQLA', 'jGmaIfG', 'n0SXrxK', 'ZZaPdaZ', 'mAvGJzi'];
var diceRand = function () {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * dicePage.length);
    return {index, score: dicePage[index]}
}
```

after calling `diceRand`, you'll get an object that might look like `{ index: 0, score: 'r0aidLn' }`.

Answer (score 0):

Save the value of the function in a variable, then use `indexOf()` with that.

```
var diceString = diceRand();
var diceScore = dicePage.indexOf(diceRand());
```

But why not just have `diceRand()` return the index in the first place, since you're apparently not using the string that it returns.

Comment: I am using the string it returns for something else. Sorry I didn't explain that. But your advice worked perfectly thank you! This is my first attempt at JavaScript/coding so I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: How were you using it for something else if you didn't assign it to a variable?